# TransactionScope Out of range valid value transalationIsolation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-core

So I have this read query to the database that I want to specify a NO-LOCK for the ORM (EF,Npoco,Nhibernate,LinqToSql), therefore I wrapped it in a transaction Scope and I specified the Transaction option which is an enum for ReadUncommitted (NOLOCK) [All in the effort to prevent database **deadlock**]

The challenge is I'm getting an exception "**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: transactionIsolationLevel**" even though the transactionScope constructor is correct based on the required values.

I'm not going out of the IsolationLevel enum so I'm not expecting an out-of-range exception thrown at runtime.

If you've faced this kind of error or familiar with something similar to this. Please kindly assist.

Thanks and below is the code sample.
***[Using scope As Transactions.TransactionScope = New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions)]*** threw the exception

```
            Dim transactionOptions = New Transactions.TransactionOptions()
            transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
            transactionOptions.Timeout = Transactions.TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
    
            Using scope As Transactions.TransactionScope = New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions)
                Using db As New DbContext
    
                  'Ambient transaction
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: it could be that your underlying data provider does not support `Read Uncommitted` isolation level. What is your database enigne?

Comment: It hasn't even gotten to the database call,

DB Engine: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so the answer was to move the transactionScope into a new class because there is a transaction conflict that should work based on the references but it is surprisingly causing the error.

At the end of the day, I resorted to storedprocedure (Faster and neat)